# Spring MVC ,Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

When i use the hibernate validator in Spring MVC project (not based on Maven) i get Exception "java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError".

From website tutorials i know that the Maven is not required if we import the hibernate validator jar files in our project ,although i import all required validator hibernate jar files in my project iam still get the exception but when i use Maven project where i move  all the same files from Spring MVC prject to maven Spring MVC project the application and validators are run well.

My question is How can i use hibernate validator without using maven and without get any exception ?

My exception :

```
java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for class: interface javax.validation.constraints.Min: @javax.validation.constraints.Min(message=must be more than 5 letters, groups=[], payload=[], value=5)
```

My controller Class :

```
package model;

import beans.Traveller;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
public class Data  {

    @RequestMapping("/ViewJSP")
    public ModelAndView method1(@Valid @ModelAttribute("Traveller1") Traveller traveller ,BindingResult bindingResult)
    {              

         if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
         {
            ModelAndView mv = new  ModelAndView("index");    
            return  mv ; 
         }  
        ModelAndView mv = new  ModelAndView("ViewJSP");    
        return  mv ;       
    }


}
```

My bean class :

```
public class Traveller {

     @Size(min=5,max=30)
     private String name ;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }  

}
```

the hibernate jar files that i import in my project :

- classmate-1.3.4
- hibernate-validator-6.0.13.Final
- jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final
- validation-api-2.0.1.Final

Answer (score 0):

Use *@Length* instead of *@Size* from *org.hibernate.validator.constraints*.

Comment: I still get the exception !

Comment: I edited the question by adding the import libraries to the controller class you can see it